# Why does my inline assembler not work as expected?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inline-assembly

Maybe I have missed something about functions or something else?
I use VS 2010.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

void swap (int& a, int& b)
{
     __asm push a
     __asm push b
     __asm pop a
     __asm pop b
     std::cout << "Inline function check: a=" << a << " b=" << b << "\n\n";
}

void main()
{
    int arg1=1, arg2=9000;
    std::cout << "Before swap we have: a=" << arg1 << " b=" << arg2 << "\n\n";
    swap(arg1, arg2);
    std::cout << "After swap we have: a=" << arg1 << " b=" << arg2;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the output?

Comment: Before swap we have: a=1 b=9000

Inline function check: a=9000 b=1

After swap we have: a=1 b=9000

Comment: I think as you passed by reference ( a pointer in reality) the assembler is using a as the pointer thus within swap you are swapping round the pointers (references), not the values.

Comment: So pointer is adress and i think that i swapped adreeses of my values. And in functions body we can see that swap is successful, but in main some fail. Oh im sorry, my english bad today.

Comment: it appears to work in the function because the pointers are swapped so a now points to b and visa versa, so the debug u have in c++ now appears to show the corrent answer.

Comment: With gcc on 32bit x86 systems, it works without problems: `void swap (int& a, int& b)
{
asm ( "pushl %0;"
 "pushl %1;"
 "popl %0;"
 "popl %1;"
 : "=r"(a),"=r"(b) : "0"(a),"1"(b) );
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass by reference with Visual Studio, the compiler passes the **address** of the referenced variable. Your swap is actually swapping the addresses that were passed to the swap function; it's not actually swapping the contents.

In order to swap the contents, you would need to dereference the pointers. Unfortunately, the compiler won't allow you to do this directly, so you'll have to use registers.

Here is a short example. This is just a demonstration; swapping the two variables can be done with far fewer instructions if you access the stack directly, instead of using `a` and `b`. It's important to note that memory can only be modified by using a register.

```
void swap(int& a, int& b) {
__asm {
    // Preserve our registers
    push eax 
    push ebx 
    push ecx 
    push edx 
    // Store the address of a in eax and b in ebx
    mov eax, a
    mov ebx, b
    // Store the value of a in ecx and b in edx
    mov ecx, [eax]
    mov edx, [ebx]
    // Swap the values pointed to by a and b
    mov [eax], edx
    mov [ebx], ecx
    // Restore the registers
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    pop eax
}
}
```

Comment: So i've used registers. But it still doesnt work. Values swap in function but inside no any effect. I have a sense, that i have big hole in understanding how c++ is working.

Comment: Inline assembler should be avoided. The compiler doesn't have to meet any sort of standards, so it can do whatever it wants with your instructions. I've added an example.

Answer (score 4):

The inline assembly doesn't know about references, so you are swapping the parameters but not their values.

References are generally implemented as pointers, in which case you swap the pointers, not the values.

Comment: Now i am fully confused. I've rewrite my function, but it dont work:

void swap (int* a, int* b)
{
 int c=*a, d=*b;
 __asm push c
 __asm push d
 __asm pop c
 __asm pop d
 a=&c; b=&d;
 std::cout << "Inline function check: a=" << *a << " b=" << *b << "\n\n";
}